# Opening new tab and running scripts in both tabs

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I'm trying to write (what I thought would be) a simple zsh script to set up my development environment. The problem I'm running into is that once I get to part of my process, that tab in the shell is devoted only to the last process when I need it to continue running other commands.

More explicitly, I need to run:

```
lein ring server-headless
```

then open a new tab, and run

```
cd ../
cd my_directory/
nodemon
```

I'm sure this has a simple solution/I should have been a better-Googler, I'm just new to this and didn't know how to word my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying this with bash/zsh/etc. I would recommend using Tmux instead :)

Take a look at Tmuxinator for this stuff: https://github.com/aziz/tmuxinator

If you don't want to use tmuxinator, with a few lines of shell code you can still make tmux do this stuff.